# auto deploy issues on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, autodeploy

I'm having issues setting up auto deploy with my github node.js repo on heroku. On the heroku side, it says "Automatic Deploys from master are enabled" and there are no restrictions on my repo for auto deploy on github. I am able to do a manual deploy fine but wanted to see if anyone has run into this problem as well and have a solution. Thanks!

Comment: What problem? You've told us what you're trying to do, but nothing about what's not working.

Comment: I'm unable to get the autodeploy working. The manual deploy works but not the automatic deploy.

Comment: As schmitty890 says below, GitHub was recovering from a major outage yesterday. Webhooks were disabled for quite a while as their data restore process completed. Automatic deploys should be working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seemed to be an issue with GitHub as I was having the exact same issue earlier today. I had my heroku app watching my master branch, so whenever a branch was merged into master, a deployment build would automatically kick off. This all of the sudden wasnt happening as of today, however the manual deploys worked as expected as you mentioned.

Seen here https://blog.github.com/ github has addressed some issues in deployment workflows that they have had issues with during today and yesterday.